# How can I sort to associated arrays by using the elements of one of them only?

Tags: java, arrays

The task was to create a program which organises a users name with their corresponding mark and displays this in descending order. I'm asking how to sort both arrays at the same time but only by comparing the elements of one of the arrays. As a restriction, I cannot use classes, only associated arrays.

```
int [] ArrMarks = new int [5];
String [] ArrNames = new String [5];
```

Button to Accept user input

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ArrNames[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Name:");
    ArrMarks[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a mark:")); 
}
```

Display button including the part which sorts the code, this is the main part I am unsure of.

```
int Hi = ArrMarks[0];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(ArrMarks[i] > Hi) {
        Hi = ArrMarks[i];
    }
}

txaDisplay.append("Names:"+"\t\t"+"Marks");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    txaDisplay.append(ArrNames[i]+"\t\t"+ArrMarks[i]+"\n");
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is your question???

Comment: @Trobbins When I run the program it does not sort the array, I'm asking for a slight modification to my code that will enable this.

Comment: Combine the name and the grades into one class, and then you can use: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question required using a sorting technique to sort the names and marks, so that the program prints the corresponding mark to the name.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5-1; i ++)
{
    for(int j = i +1; j < 5; j++)
{
 if (ArrMarks[i] < ArrMarks[j]) 

 {
    //sorting the names
    String temp = ArrNames[i];
    ArrNames[i] = ArrNames[j];
    ArrNames[j] = temp;

    //sorting the marks
    int temp1 = ArrMarks[i];
    ArrMarks[i] = ArrMarks[j];
    ArrMarks[j] = temp1;  

}  

}   
txaDisplay.append("Names:"+"\t\t"+"Marks"+"\n");

        txaDisplay.append(ArrNames[i]+"\t\t"+ArrMarks[i]+"\n"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to give a suggestion. Use lists instead of arrays. This kind of coding is not a good conventional way of coding. I will show a conventional way to handle the issue. You may take this if you like.

Create another class `Mark.java` with the following content

```
class Mark {
    Integer mark;
    String name;

    public Integer getMark() {
        return this.mark
    }
    public void setMark(Integer mark) {
        this.mark = mark
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Then in your current class create a `List` of this class.

```
List<Mark> marks = new ArrayList<Mark>();
```

Then after reading content from the user, you can add them to the list like following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Mark mark = new Mark();
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name:");
    Integer mark = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mark:")); 
    marks.add(mark)
}
```

Write a comparator class named `MarkComparator.java`. It deals with the sorting part.

```
public class MarkComparator implements Comparator<Mark> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Mark m1, Mark m2) {
        return m1.getMark().compareTo(m2.getMark());
    }
}
```

The use

```
Collections.sort(marks, new MarkComparator());
```

Now the `List<Mark>` of `marks` will be sorted.

You may then view the list the same way.

```
txaDisplay.append("Names:"+"\t\t"+"Marks");
for (Mark mark : marks)
{
    txaDisplay.append(mark.getName()+"\t\t"+mark.getMark()+"\n");
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but OP cannot use classes =\